# Is there any way two configure four way relationship with two two tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to migrate the models but I'm getting an error as

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property" due to relationship constraints.

I don't know how to configure this relationship

```
public class Currency
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Symbol { get; set; }      

    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ExchangeRate> ExchangeRates { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ExchangeRate> QuotedExchangeRates { get; set; }
}


public class ExchangeRate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }      

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public decimal Rate { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    public Currency BaseCurrency { get; set; }

    public Currency QuoteCurrency { get; set; }
}
```

Details view:

[image]

Comment: You will need to configure it using the fluent API.

Comment: It is simpler if you avoid creating two-direction relationships between two entity types. Try to choose one of them as owner and the other would be the owned entity type.
Maybe you are better making `ExchangeRate` owner and making `Currency` a simple entity and that depends on your application and other relationships with other entities. But if you do so you can access exchange rates through ExchangeRates collection and no need to use the navigation properties on Currency to simplify the model.

Comment: @poke Can you describe it in detail how I define it in OnModelCreating Method

Comment: @Neptune can you describe using code 
Thanks, Man :)

Comment: @Neptune An owned entity does not appear to make sense for this case since a `Currency` makes sense to exist as a separate entity, and embedding an exchange rate between to currencies would be somewhat odd to be embedded in _one_ of the currencies.

Comment: @MKhizarBajwa Check out [the docs on configuring relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#fluent-api).